Inverse function theorem for $W^{2,n}\cap W^{1,\infty}$ functions
Let $n\ge 2$, $f:B_1\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $f\in W^{2,n}\cap W^{1,\infty}(B_1)$, $\text{det}(Df)>c>0$, where $B_1$ is the unit ball. Can we show that $f$ is a homeomorphism in a neighborhood of the origin (with $f^{-1}\in W^{2,n}_{loc}\cap W^{1,\infty}_{loc}$)?
When $n=2$, the $W^{2,n}$ condition is critical: consider the example $$f(z):=\frac{z^2}{|z|}.$$  When $n\ge 3$, in the paper "Sobolev mappings with integrable dilatations" by Heinonen and Koskela (MR1241287, Zbl 0792.30016), it is proved that $f$ is open under much looser conditions, so what is remaining is injectivity.

Not a helpful comment at all, but I really like this question.

It seems that the answer is “yes”:
I. Fonseca, W. Gangbo, “Local Invertibility of Sobolev Functions”, SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis 1995 26:2, 280-304

I’m not surprised that this problem is difficult enough for a paper - the inverse function theorem and its variants are some of the most intricate theorems in the undergraduate analysis curriculum I think. At least for me they are hard to intuit, especially when you ask for lower regularity.

I read that paper. Indeed, it used much looser conditions and proved local invertibility at a.e. point but not all the points in $B_1$. The latter is what I’m looking for.

@TianLAN are you sure you read the paper? It's written in the first page (3rd line below equation (3)) that if $\det(\nabla v) \ge \gamma >0$ and $v\in W^{1,q}(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^n)$ for $q\ge n(n-1)$ (note that this is true for your $f$) then $v, v^{-1}$ are homeomorphisms, and $v\circ v^{-1} = v^{-1} \circ v = \textrm{Id}$ hold everywhere (not just a.e.). A few lines below, you can also read why, by a result of Heinonen and Koskela, in this case, and for $n\ge 3$, actually $v$ is an open map.

@MicheleCaselli Yes I'm sure. Please note the example $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{|z|}$ Lipschitz with constant positive Jacobian but not invertible near $0$ in dimension $2$. Ιn higher dimensions similar examples can be constructed. You may find the complete version of that paper, in which the inverse map $w$ and domain $D$ depend on $x_0$ which is a.e. in Τheorem 3.1.

@TianLAN Oh I see you are right, this is sharper than i thought, my bad.
